# When to kill an activity's initialisation thread

Tags: android

In order to ensure my acivity remains responsive to sensor inputs, I'm currently starting a new thread within the onCreate() method which initialises all requisite resources whilst the UI thread displays a loading message and logo. If the user presses the home button during this initialisation process, I'm using the activity's on pause() method in order to signal this thread to wait until otherwise notified. If the activity is in fact destroyed whilst in this wait state or when the back button is pressed, I'm currently relying on the ondestroy() method in order to interrupt and destroy the incomplete initialisation thread.

Unfortunately, when resuming the application by selecting it's icon from the home screen, the activity's onCreate() method is sometimes called creating a new initialisation thread without ever having called the onDestroy() method in order to kill the existing initialisation thread. If onDestroy() isn't always called in this scenario, how can I determine whether or not the existing initialisation thread needs to be destroyed?

Any help and/or advice regarding this matter would be very much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your needs but perhaps it is sufficient to alter the launchmode of your activity in manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

> In contrast, "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

This would prevent onCreate being called before onDestroy.

Edit:

Another possible solution would be to manually check if there are other processes running your application in e.g. onCreate:

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
        if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(this.getPackageName())) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter > 1) {
            // send broadcast to make other activities call finish() or the like
        }
    }
```

Hesitated with posting this answer as it feels abit hackish but since no other proposals have been posted until now you might as well give it a try.

I used it for a different scenario where the phone would sometimes start my app twice after boot. With this code I could prevent the second start to complete by simply calling finish.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know about this attribute at all. Unfortunately I have a multitude of activities which will be initialised in this manner, and they must be allowed to exists anywhere within the activity stack.

Comment: Edited my answer with another proposal (don't know if you get informed automatically about that)

Comment: As the waiting thread is holding a reference to the destroyed activity/view, the system is also unable to remove it cleanly and thus causing a backup on the stack. Again some nice info, thanks buddy :) I think the easiest way around this problem is to always kill the init thread in the onPause() method and restart it within the onResume() method. Marked as answered due to the valuable info you gave. Once again, thanks mate.

Comment: Cheers :) a shame we didn't find a working solution though. My last idea would be to refactor the init thread into an IntentService. This way you will not have to worry about managing the thread.